# How to open my app from lock screen without unlock the device Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to develop regular app for android devices but I want that the app will be opened from lock screen without unlock the device.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: In Android, it is only possible on the latest api levels. They're called lockscreen widgets I believe. Do a google search on that. If you want to target earlier apis, HTC has a special api as well, but that only works on HTC devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4k0OFFa4Us 
If you look the video you see that doesnt depend about your code, that depend about the software you use to the lock screen.

I left you some examples:
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lockscreen.one.touch.fr